# Ajax.BeginForm не правильно конструирует Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть форма для добавления товара в корзину:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCart","Cart" , new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "res" }, new { style = "margin-top: 20px" }))
    {
        <div class="text-center">
            @Html.HiddenFor(r => r.Id)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-for-product" value="Добавить в корзину" />
        </div>
    }
```

Вот что генерируется в итоги:

```
<form action="/Products/AddCart?Length=4" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#res" id="form0" method="post" style="margin-top: 20px" novalidate="novalidate">        <div class="text-center">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="Значением поля Id должно быть число." data-val-required="Требуется поле Id." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="24">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-for-product" value="Добавить в корзину">
        </div>
</form>
```

Ключевое тут в том что **action="/Products/AddCart?Length=4"**, а должно **action="/Cart/AddCart"**. В хелпере указан контроллер Cart и метод действия AddCart. А хелпер генерирует странный **action**. У меня вопрос, почему хелпер формирует странный **action**?? И, как из хелпера можно решить эту проблему??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде вызывается не тот перегруженый вариант `Ajax.BeginForm`, на который Вы рассчитывали. К перечисленным параметрам подходит

[public static MvcForm BeginForm(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,System.Object%29)

а нужен

[public static MvcForm BeginForm(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    object htmlAttributes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,System.Object%29)

Из вариантов с четырьмя параметрами компилятором выбран такой, в котором типы Ваших значений могут быть приведены к ожидаемым. Cтрока `"Cart"` в этом случае рассматривается как `object routeValues` - обратите внимание на свойство `Length=4` после `?` в адресной строке. А контроллер берется текущий.

Правильно:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCart", "Cart", null, 
  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "res" }, new { style = "margin-top: 20px" }))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.